# Unable to connect localhost using HyperV Container on Win10 1903

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v, windows-container

I was just upgraded to Windows 10 1903 from 1809, then my docker become a little bit weird. Here are my current situation:

- OS: `Microsoft Windows [ver 10.0.18362.116]`
- Hyper-V: Installed. I have only one VSwitch called `Default Switch`.
- I reinstalled Docker Desktop for Windows v2.0.0.3. (`Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962`)
- The docker can run without problem. Only the network issue!

Here is what I tried:

1. Run iis container in "process" isolation mode.

   ```
   docker run -d --rm -p 80:80 --isolation process mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-1903
   ```

   I can connect to port 80 through `localhost`.
2. Run iis container in "hyperv" isolation mode.

   ```
   docker run -d --rm -p 80:80 --isolation hyperv mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-1903
   ```

   I **can't** connect to port 80 through localhost. I was okay before I upgrade to Windows 10 1903.

I almost tried everything I can try. I just can't get my localhost (loopback interface) works.

1. I tried on the other machine. When docker started, there is a `nat` VSwitch will be created by docker.  It doesn't work on my machine.
2. I tried to create a new VMSwitch and named `nat` but doesn't works.
3. I tried to run `.\WindowsContainerNetworking-LoggingAndCleanupAide.ps1 -Cleanup -ForceDeleteAllSwitches` using [this script](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/master/windows-server-container-tools/CleanupContainerHostNetworking). Restart the computer. It doesn't works.
4. I completely removed Hyper-V and [Docker](https://success.docker.com/article/how-to-completely-remove-docker-in-windows-10). Reinstall again doesn't works.
5. I tried to list networks defined in hnsdiag. (`hnsdiag list networks`) Then deleted the `nat` network. Restart the HNS service. Restart Docker again. It doesn't work.

May I ask what else I can do for my docker network settings?